# Windows Phone - minimum version to target as of Jan 2013

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

We've currently considering porting an iOS app over to Windows phone. However, if we do go ahead with this, we're a little confused about which version to target as a minimum.

I guess there's a much 'larger' Windows Phone 7 audience out there at present, but as it's never really taken off in a big way, would it be better to start off with 8, and focus on getting up to speed with its libraries etc? (Presumably, future versions of Windows Phone are more likely to be evolutions of 8, rather than the jump from 7 to 8?)

Any tips, statistics on user bases etc would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the features you need to have in your application. If you don't require any of the advanced features that come with Windows Phone 8, consider targeting 7.1 version. You can even detect if you are running on Windows Phone 8 OS from your WP7 application and use features available on WP8 OS for that matter. Consider checking out [mangopollo](http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/) for that.

Windows Phone 7 is still selling and all users on it will be grateful if you provide your application for them. Keep that in mind.